# Tar recursive compare with original folder

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, sh, tar

I have a `.tgz` file made with `tar cvzf tartest.tgz tester/*` and if I list the tar with `tar --list -f tartest.tgz` file, I have the following structure

```
 tester/2017-08-02_131404.png
 tester/cfg.pdf
 tester/tests/
 tester/tests/1.png
 tester/tests/2.png
 tester/tests/3.png
 tester/tests/4.png
 tester/tests/5.png
```

If I compare the tar with the original folder by using `tar -df tartest.tgz tester/*`, everything ok, no problems, no errors

If I add the file *20171006_183137.png* in the **tester** folder, and retry, I get an error, as expected:

```
 tar: tester/20171006_183137.png: Not found in archive
 tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

If I add the file *20171006_183137.png* in the **tester/tests** folder, and retry, I get no error and blank output.

If I add **-v** option during last test, I just get the list of the files in the tar.

Is there a way to recursive compare tar with original folder and subfolders?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/tar_2.html), `tar` behaves as intended.

> You should note again that while `--compare` (`-d`) does cause tar to
>   report back on files in the archive that do not exist in the file
>   system, tar will ignore files in the active file system that do not
>   exist in the archive.

The error you are getting for `tar -df tartest.tgz tester/*` is indeed an *error* (!) not a message like »*archive and directory differ*«. `tar` does not know how to treat files that are not in the archive.

If you also want to compare the other way around, you could use the method described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16752/187122) (mount or unpack the archive and use `diff -r` against the original directory).

If you are only interested in a file's existence and not content, access dates, and so on, you could list the file names from the archive and from the original directory and compare them with `diff`:

```
diff <(tar -tf tartest.tgz | sort) <(find tester/ | sort)
```

The command works only if there are no file names with linebreaks in them.
Use `diff -y` or the `comm` command for a more readable output.